# less-middleware not compiling, getting 404

Tags: node.js, express, less

I have a node.js server running with less-middleware. From my understanding, it compiles on the fly and places the css file in the destination/same(if not specified) folder.

My problem is I'm getting a 404 error on the get request for the css file:

Err: `GET http://webserver/public/less/blog-reset.css 404 (Not Found)`

Here is what I'm working with:

**web.js**

```
//requiring dependencies
var express = require("express");
var logfmt = require("logfmt");
var lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware');
var hogan = require('hogan-express');
var path = require('path');

//all environments
var app = module.exports = express();
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.use(logfmt.requestLogger());
app.use(lessMiddleware(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.set('layout',path.join(__dirname,'src','views','blog-layout'));
app.enable('view cache');
app.engine('.html',hogan);

//page routing called after env loads
require('./src/router');

//listening port
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

**blog-layout.html**

```
<head>
        <title>EpiBlog</title>
        <link href='/public/less/blog-reset.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>
<body>
        {{{yield}}}
</body>
```

**directory layout**

```
ROOT
   public
      less
   src
   web.js
```

**Versions**

- less-middleware v0.2.1-beta
- express v4.0.0

What I've tried:

- using `app.use(lessMiddleware)({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));` (apparently the old way of doing it)
- using `app.use(lessMiddleware(path.join(__dirname,'public','less')));`
- moving `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));` from web.js to router.js
- toying with different paths
- moving contents of router.js to web.js
- specifying the destination using

this:

```
app.use(lessMiddleware(path.join(__dirname, 'source', 'less'), {
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
}));
```

Comment: I am having the same problems

Comment: @Tirithen thanks. I've been at this for 2 days now. I'm going to keep updating this question as I go. We will get this one! <3 SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem was:

```
<link href='/public/less/blog-reset.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

should have been:

```
<link href='/less/blog-reset.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

i read that:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='css/styles.css')
```

was paired with directory structure:

```
myapp
+-public
  +-css
    +-styles.less
```

which led me to believe that this call:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

makes the request assume `/public/` is the parent so i was being redundant calling `/public/less/blog-reset.css`

reference was found here: [express.js less compiler: can not get work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502333/express-js-less-compiler-can-not-get-work)